# How to install Pipelight on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, pipelight

Since the [PPA of Pipelight](https://launchpad.net/%7Epipelight/+archive/ubuntu/stable) was taken down, I cannot install this plugin anymore. Without a Silverlight plugin, [Sky Go](https://www.sky.com/watch/sky-go/) (a payed TV stream) won't run. I have set up an older laptop with Ubuntu just for the TV.

Does anyone got a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Pipelight uses the NPAPI, which is no longer supported by modern browsers; that's probably why it was taken down.

Silverlight itself reached EOL in 2012.

You might be able to manually install the plugin with an older version of Firefox.

Comment: SL actually reaches EOL in October 2021 (Crome removed the NPAPI in Sept 2015 and Firefox in March 2017). Currently only IE 11 (EOL with Silverlight) and Pale Moon still support SL (as far as I know).